# SQL MAX and GROUP BY with WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

Given the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `device_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `distincted` BIT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
    `timestamp_detected` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `idx1` (`device_id`),
    INDEX `idx2` (`device_id`, `timestamp_detected`),
    CONSTRAINT `test_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`device_id`) REFERENCES `device` (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

I want to perform a groupwise max on `timestamp_detected` grouped by `device_id` with the following:

```
SELECT lh1.id, lh1.timestamp_detected, lh1.device_id FROM test as lh1, 
    (SELECT MAX(timestamp_detected) as max_timestamp_detected, device_id FROM test GROUP BY device_id) as lh2 
    WHERE lh1.timestamp_detected = lh2.max_timestamp_detected 
        AND lh1.device_id = lh2.device_id;
```

This yields the following results when run with explain:

```
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys                                           | key                          | key_len | ref                                      | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL   | NULL                                                    | NULL                         | NULL    | NULL                                     |   15 | Using where              |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | lh1        | ref   | FK_location_history_device,device_id_timestamp_detected | device_id_timestamp_detected | 9       | lh2.device_id,lh2.max_timestamp_detected |    1 | Using index              |
|  2 | DERIVED     | test       | range | FK_location_history_device,device_id_timestamp_detected | device_id_timestamp_detected | 4       | NULL                                     |   15 | Using index for group-by |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+------+--------------------------+
```

Now there is a requirement that only those rows with `distincted` = 1 should be included in the results. I modified the query to the following:

```
SELECT lh1.id, lh1.timestamp_detected, lh1.device_id FROM test as lh1, 
        (SELECT MAX(timestamp_detected) as max_timestamp_detected, device_id FROM test WHERE distincted = 1 GROUP BY device_id) as lh2 
        WHERE lh1.timestamp_detected = lh2.max_timestamp_detected 
            AND lh1.device_id = lh2.device_id;
```

It returns the results correctly however it seems to take longer. Running an explain yields the following:

```
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys                                           | key                          | key_len | ref                                      | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL   | NULL                                                    | NULL                         | NULL    | NULL                                     |  860 | Using where |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | lh1        | ref   | FK_location_history_device,device_id_timestamp_detected | device_id_timestamp_detected | 9       | lh2.device_id,lh2.max_timestamp_detected |    1 | Using index |
|  2 | DERIVED     | test       | index | FK_location_history_device,device_id_timestamp_detected | FK_location_history_device   | 4       | NULL                                     |  860 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
```

I tried adding the `distincted` column to index `idx2` to no avail. How can I optimize this query?

Comment: I don't understand the outer GROUP BY

Comment: Oh! Well spotted. It seems to be redundant. I'll edit the query.

Comment: If you can make a unique index with which you can search, it's gonna make the query run much faster

Comment: Remove this index: INDEX idx1 (device_id). Also, there's an implication that (`device_id`, `timestamp_detected`) is UNIQUE, so you may as well make that explicit. Other than that, this query is optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is:

```
SELECT lh1.id, lh1.timestamp_detected, lh1.device_id
FROM test lh1 JOIN
     (SELECT MAX(timestamp_detected) as max_timestamp_detected, device_id
      FROM test
      WHERE distincted = 1
      GROUP BY device_id
     ) as lh2 
     on lh1.timestamp_detected = lh2.max_timestamp_detected AND
        lh1.device_id = lh2.device_id;
```

For this query, I would suggest indexes on `test(distincted, device_id, time_stamp_detected)` and `test(device_id, timestamp_detected)`.

I also wonder if you would get better performance with this equivalent query:

```
SELECT lh1.id, lh1.timestamp_detected, lh1.device_id
FROM test lh1
WHERE distincted = 1 AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM test t
                  WHERE t.distincted = 1 AND
                        t.device_id = lh1.device_id AND
                        t.timestamp_detected > lh1.timestamp_detected
                 );
```

And these two indexes: `test(distincted)` and `test(device_id, timestamp_detected, distincted)`.

Comment: Adding the `distincted` column to the index didn't work at first however rearranging the order of the columns in the index to `device_id`, `distincted`, `timestamp_detected` did the trick.